# OCX methods execution monitoring

Tags: com

I have a OCX control which is loaded in Internet Explorer (used to show stream from IP camera). To see live video I have to properly connect to server etc. using methods of created object. The best idea will be to monitor which methods are called from IE. **Is there any possibility to monitor these calls** and parameters with for example plug-in for IE or some API monitor program?

[image: OCX information in OLEView]
[image: Methods details]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use API Monitor available here: http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor
As this is probably a custom OCX, you will have to write a custom headers file, you can this as an example: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/39850-generate-headers-for-mscomm32ocx/

Comment: Creating custom headers by hand seems to be time consuming and error prone but that software looks great, Also author promises that in the next version that step will be autmated. Great!

Answer (score 2):

As 3asm_ suggested, it would be best to try API Monitor first.

If that doesn't work, though, an alternative would be to attach to IE with a debugger and set logging breakpoints on the entrypoint of each method in the OCX. You can then see the order in which IE calls them and the arguments that are passed.

Comment: That's also a very good idea, you may use Immunity Debugger as it has a plugin for listing and setting breakpoints with the !activex command

Comment: @3asm_ do you have a link or name to that plugin?